# Unable to create new objects of a model after referencing a field on another model as FK - django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have overrided django auth model to a custom one, where I declare the USERNAME_FIELD as phone_number. OTPLog model is intended to keep a log record of the messages sent to the clients. To remove duplication of keeping phone numbers in db, I referenced the phone_number field in OTPLog to phone_number field in User as FK.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=11,
        validators=[RegexValidator(regex=consts.PHONE_REGEX_PATTERN)]
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
```

```
class OTPLog(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=default_otp_duration)
    phone_number = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, to_field='phone_number', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_index=True)
```

Now making an object of OTPLog with phone_number is not possible any more, as the following exception is risen:

`otplog = OTPLog.objects.create(phone_number='01145279126')`
will give **ValueError: Cannot assign "'01145279126'": "OTPLog.phone_number" must be a "User" instance**.

After making an object of User and calling `otplog = OTPLog.objects.create(phone_number=user)` the object is created successfully, but that is not the way I expect it work. I would simply need a FK constraint, where if a user with a given phone_number does not exist, the otplog object could not be created.

How would I resolve the issue?

Comment: Since it is a foreign key field, if you don't provide object reference, you will have to modify key to be of **id** field for the referenced model. Just append **_id** in your *phone_number* argument:--**OTPLog.objects.create(phone_number_id='1234567890')**

Comment: Please see that your **expiry_date** field is a datetime field which accepts date/time, instead of integer duration. So you may have to modify it to be **created+default_time_duration** in a save method.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. But it seems a little confusing to me, if I add db_column='phone_number' and migrate it to DB, your solution still works. Which is odd, since there is no field by the name of 'phone_number_id' on the corresponding table of OTPLog in DB. But it can be accessed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OTPLog(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=default_otp_duration)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.phone_number
```

**And to create a new OTPLog object.**

```
user = User.objects.get(phone_number='01145279126')
otplog = OTPLog.objects.create(user=user)
```

Comment: The OP explicitly does not want this solution, he does not want to get user object in a variable before calling for OTP.